# Optional variable match?

Tags: perl

I would like to write a regex that can extract the 2, 3, or 4 characters in the following strings:

```
a b
a b c
a b c d
```

I wrote the following code to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = ("a b", "a b c", "a b c d");

while (defined (my $line = shift @a)) {

    my ($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4) = "";
    ($c1, $c2, $c3) = $line =~ /^(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)?.*?/;
    print "$c1, $c2, $c3\n";
}
```

However, the above fails because `$c3` cannot be found in the first two strings. How can I make `$c3` and `$c4` optional, so the regex doesn't fail when there is nothing to match for those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How can I make $c3 and $c4 optional, so the regex doesn't fail when there is nothing to match for those?*

Unless you *must* use individuals variables, consider using an array to hold the characters you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = ( "a b", "a b c", "a b c d" );

for my $line (@a) {
    my @chars = split ' ', $line;
    #my @chars = $line =~ /\S+/g; # Or use this regex to capture the chars
    print join( ', ', @chars ), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a, b
a, b, c
a, b, c, d
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does `print +` mean?: Append newline for each array element?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes - It disambiguates the statement so `print` knows how to handle it.  Have redone the line to avoid using the leading `+`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is more practical than regex,

```
for my $line (@a) {

    my ($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4) = split " ", $line;
    print "$c1, $c2, $c3\n";
}
```

Comment: Very beautiful solution. How do I avoid the `Use of uninitialized value $c3 in concatenation (.) or string`?

Answer (score 1):

To account for any number of fields in your string, I suggest you use an array instead of a list of scalar variables.

In any case, if you have variables like `$f1`, `$f2`, `$f3`, `$f4` then it is a sign that you probably want an array `@f` instead. Then you can use `$f[0]`, `$f[1]`, `$f[2]`, `$f[3]`.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = ('a b', 'a b c', 'a b c d');

for (@data) {
  my @fields = split;
  print join(', ', @fields), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
a, b
a, b, c
a, b, c, d
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got some good answers using `split`. But you can do this easily with regexes too. You just need to attack it from a slightly different direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @strings = ("a b", "a b c", "a b c d");

foreach (@strings) {
  my @matches = /(\S+)/g;
  say "@matches";
}
```